# Envio de notificaciones firebase desde una tarea programada en mi hosting

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, asp

He pedido a mi hosting que me cree una tarea programada para que ejecute un script hecho en ASP clasica y Javascript.
Lo que pretendía es enviar unos correos todos los días. De paso quise hacer una modificación para que enviase una notificacion con Firebase a ciertos usuarios de Android con mi APK instalada.
Esto no me funciona, sólo envía los correos.
Sin embargo, si abro ese script en el Navegador **SI** envia esas notificaciones y los correos.
Y es sobre lo que me gustaria que me ayudaran, pues ando perdido.
En el código ASP llamo a la función **notifica(eltoken, eltitulo, elbody)**

El código es el siguiente:

```
    <!-- Firebase -->  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>  
<script>  
  
const admin = require("firebase-admin");  
const serviceAccount = require("./Mi_Fichero.json");  
  
admin.initializeApp({  
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),  
});  
  
  
  var firebaseConfig = {  
       apiKey: "Mi_APIKEY",  
       authDomain:"Mi_Dominio",  
       projectId:  "MI_Projectid",  
       storageBucket: "Mi_Storage",   
       messagingSenderId:  "MisenderID",  
       appId: "Mi_APIID",  
  };  
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();  
</script>  
  
  
<script>  
function permisos(){  
    messaging.requestPermission()  
    .then(function () {  
        console.log("Permiso concedido.......");  
        return messaging.getToken();  
    })  
        .then(function (token) {  
        console.log("Token de mi registro:", token);      
    })  
        .catch(function (error) {  
        console.log("Error al solicitar permiso:", error);  
        return "ERROR";  
    });       
  
};  
  
</script>  
  
<script>  
    function notifica(mi_token, titulo, body) {  
    if (mi_token.length > 10 ){  
      
        // primero pido el permiso...........  
            permisos();  
              
            // envio una notificacion
            fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                  "Authorization": "key=Mi_AUTORIZACION_KEY"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    to:  mi_token,
                    notification: {
                    title: titulo,
                    body: body,
                    click_action: "https://www.miweb.com"
                  }
                })
              })

        .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Notificación enviada:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error al enviar la notificación:", error);
        });};

};

</script>
```

He modificado mi script cambiando el Javascipt por codigo ASP y lo he dejado asi:

```
<%
Dim objXMLHTTP, strRequest, strResponse, strFCMServerKey, strDeviceToken

' Clave del servidor de Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
strFCMServerKey = "TU_SERVER_KEY"

' Token de registro del dispositivo al que deseas enviar la notificación
strDeviceToken = "TOKEN_DEL_DISPOSITIVO"

' Construir el cuerpo de la solicitud JSON
strRequest = "{""to"": """ & strDeviceToken & """,""notification"": {""title"": ""Título de la notificación"",""body"": ""Cuerpo de la notificación""}}"

' Crear el objeto XMLHTTP para hacer la solicitud HTTP
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "POST", "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", False

' Configurar las cabeceras de la solicitud
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "key=" & strFCMServerKey

' Enviar la solicitud HTTP
objXMLHTTP.send strRequest

' Obtener la respuesta
strResponse = objXMLHTTP.responseText

' Procesar la respuesta (opcional)
If objXMLHTTP.status = 200 Then
    ' La notificación se envió exitosamente
    Response.Write "Notificación enviada con éxito."
Else
    ' Ocurrió un error al enviar la notificación
    Response.Write "Error al enviar la notificación: " & objXMLHTTP.statusText
End If

' Liberar el objeto XMLHTTP
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
%>
```

Pero el resultado es el mismo....

Comment: Cómo lanzas la tarea en el servidor? no es lo mismo lanzar el interprete de ASP, que no va a ejecutar el javascript, que lanzar un navegador que pueda interpretar el javascript (pero que es poco probable que puedas lanzar). Pregunto, porque obviamente eso hace toda la diferencia y porque supongo que el correo lo envías con asp y no con javascript (eso explica por qué si envía el correo y no las notificaciones).

Comment: La tarea en el servidor no se cómo la ejecuta. Yo se lo pedi al administrador para que ejecutase a una hora cada día y le di el nombre del fichero ASP. Yo no tengo permisos para hacerlo.
La cuestión es qué hacer en el Javascript para lograrlo. Si es que se puede...

Comment: Quizás sea momento de preguntar al administrador cómo la está ejecutando. Comentale que el script de ASP genera javascript que necesitas que sea ejecutado (por un browser) como parte de la ejecución de la tarea programada y él te dirá si eso es posible o no y, de serlo, hará los cambios en la programación de dicha tarea. No hay nada que puedas hacer, en javascript, para que ese mismo javascript sea interpretado y ejecutado.

Comment: He cambiado el javascript por codigo ASP y el resultado es el mismo. He editado la pregunta. Gracias por tu interes.

Comment: La salida si es ""Notificación enviada con éxito.", al ejecutar la tarea programada, o es "Error al enviar la notificacion"? En este caso, ¿cuál es el texto del error?

Comment: Cuando lo hacer el servidor no me entero, evidentemente, pero si hago la prueba en localhost si me sale el mensaje de notificación enviada. Pero no la envia!.

Comment: Dado que se está ejecutando en el servidor, habría que tener esa salida. Sé que te resulta complicado, pero sin esas piezas de información no creo que encuentres la  ayuda que buscas.

Comment: En localhost sale:
Error al enviar la notificación: Bad Request

Answer (score -1):

despues de varios intentos y obtener mediante correos los datos intermedios que se generaba, he conseguido que me envie notificaciones con el código ASP.
Un problema que tuve es que al cambiar los textos por variables no ponía bien las comillas, cosa que me ha pasado varias veces con ASP. Hacerlo con Javascript para otro dia...
Problema resuelto. Gracias por tu interés ***jachguate***

Comment: Hola Huno, que bueno que lo hayas resuelto, podrías mostrar la linea que generó el error y la corregida, para que pueda servir para otro usuario que tenga el mismo problema?, de paso puede que te ganes algún puntito de reputación, aparte de eso, cuando quieras notificar a alguien debes hacerlo así: @jachguate, ahora está notificado de que lo mencionaste.

Comment: @MarcePuente no. la red no funciona asi.. arrobar a alguien aqui, no funciona, salvo en los comentarios, y salvo si participo de los mismos.. Ni por la respuesta, ni por tu comentario, ha recibido una notificacion... Esto no es una red social y no se puede arrobar a personas salvo que hayan participado....

Comment: @gbianchi, interesante, no lo sabía, gracias!!!

Comment: Para que conste, la linea con el error era:

' Construir el cuerpo de la solicitud JSON
strRequest = "{""to"": """ & strDeviceToken & """,""notification"": {""title"": ""Título de la notificación"",""body"": ""Cuerpo de la notificación""}}"